# Is there a "Fit to Canvas" option in Photoshop like there is in Fireworks?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, adobe-fireworks

I am a Fireworks user new to Photoshop. In FW there is the very handy "fit to canvas" button in the properties panel at the bottom which when clicked snaps the image to the canvas by adjusting the canvas's size to be no larger than the image.

Is there such a tool in PS?

Comment: I miss Fireworks :D

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The closest you'll get is the [`Trim…`](http://cbtcafe.com/photoshop/trim/index.html) command in the `Image` menu.

Comment: If the content is bigger than the canvas it's not working as Fireworks 'Fit to canvas' tool. Only when the content is smaller than the canvas it works fine.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo As I said, it's the closest you'll get. If it's something you need to do often, it's relatively straightforward to make a photoshop action to change the canvas size to something arbitrarily large so that the content is surrounded by blank space, then use the trim command.

Comment: @ghoppe : Actually, in an instance where the content is larger than the canvas, "Reveal All" is right there in the Image menu – no recording an action required.

Comment: You could just increase the canvas size to anything that is bigger than your image, and then use trim.

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Photoshop CC 2014 at the moment and could simply achieve that by doing `Image > Reveal All.`

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer but I've been struggling with this forever and didn't know "Reveal All" existed. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Unless the image is smaller than the canvas

Comment: You just need to make the canvas smaller than the image then reveal all, and it'll expand just enough to fit the image.

Answer (score 5):

- use rectangular select (<kbd>M</kbd>) over the whole image
- copy the image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- `File > New...`
- on `Preset` click `Clipboard`
- then paste it there (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Comment: This is usually what I do, no matter the editor.
Seems if you have a freshly filled clipboard in Photoshop CC 2015, the preset will be already configured to `Clipboard` already, with the dimensions of the the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: Edit > Preferences > General > and check the box that says "Resize Image During Place"
Then when you place an image, it will fit it to your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You could always simply crop close to the edges of your content. Zoom in to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use crop , select the width and height of the image for the canvas , and the canvas will adjust for you

Answer (score 0):

go to your preferences (command K). check the box  "resize image during place"

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a lot of layers and the other suggested solutions don't work.

You can always go to image > Canvas and make a note of the dimensions.
[image]

Then choose your image, CTRL & T for Transform and enter in the canvas dimensions.

You can click the little chain if you want it to keep it's proportions then just enter either the width or the height.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:
Replace the 100% width in the topbar by the width in pixels of your canvas. (Replace the % with 'px'). Be sure the Keep Aspect Ration chain-icon is active.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to give a precise margin distance between object or product in already clipped images in a transparent background you can get it by:

1. Image > Trim > Transparent pixels and click all sides.
2. Image > Canvas size: Relative and add millimeters or inches

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, found it while hoping there was finally a better solution for this but since Photoshop is horrid seems there is not. The only solutions I have found is to copy the layer and do a new document based on whats in the clipboard. The other alternative is to work with a canvas much larger then you anticipate.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Have you seen that this already have an accepted answer which in my eyes seems to be correct? (Especially if you read the comments as well.) I think you are missing the possibility to "Image > Reveal All" followed by "Image > Trim".

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution... use a Script:
https://github.com/RetoqueFactoria/photoshopscripts/blob/master/ES%20Encajar%20Capa%20en%20Lienzo.jsx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110546)

Answer (score -1):

Using menu command "File...Automate...Fit Image" is one option.

Answer (score -2):

In Photoshop its alt+i+r at the same time.